# Java sample code non-static method called without object

Tags: java

Just reading Thinking in Java here is the question
How do these methods(contents(), to()) are called without any reference? 
do not pay attention for this(
(klklklklklklklklklklklklklklklklk) i have only this question. i think it is understandable )

```
    public class Parcel2 {
    class Contents {
    private int i = 11;
    public int value() { return i; }
    }
    class Destination {
    private String label;
    Destination(String whereTo) {
    label = whereTo;
    }
    String readLabel() { return label; }
    }
    public Destination to(String s) {
    return new Destination(s);
    }
    public Contents contents() {
    return new Contents();
    }
    public void ship(String dest) {
    Contents c = contents();
    Destination d = to(dest);
    System.out.println(d.readLabel());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parcel2 p = new Parcel2();
    p.ship("Tasmania");
    Parcel2 q = new Parcel2();
    // Defining references to inner classes:
    Parcel2.Contents c = q.contents();
    Parcel2.Destination d = q.to("Borneo");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Never post code as an image. And in `ship()` (your highlighted method), the reference is **`this`** (and neither `contents()` or `to` are `static`).

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image! Reasons: users using screen readers can't read it and the code can't be copy/pasted. Please edit the actual code into your question.

Comment: Does making the inner classes static help fix things?

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557) for details on why posting images of code isn't allowed. Images of code are difficult to read, can't be copied and pasted into IDEs, and can't be searched for.

Answer (score 1):

Your highlighted method (**ship**) is an instance method of the class Parcel2,
thus they are visible within this class and can therefore 
be called from other instance methods within the same class.
NB: Implicitly you're using the **this** reference to call **to** and **contents** from your **ship**.

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You're *not* calling them without a reference/object. You're calling instance methods from another instance method, which is perfectly acceptable.